# updating database blobs with otl crashes

Tags: c++, oracle, otl

I'm writing a simple application to correct a certain byte in a binary blob that's stored in a database. I use OTL to connect my C++ program to the database.
Reading the data and manipulation works fine, but when I want to write it back to the database, the program dies.

The code:

```
try
{
    std::string updateQuery = "UPDATE tbtptemplates "
                  "  SET tptemplate=:tp<BLOB> "
                  "WHERE afisid=:aid<INT>";

    otl_long_string blob(&stp(), theSizeOfBlob);
    blob.set_len(theSizeOfBlob);

    otl_stream str(1, updateQuery.c_str(), theDbConnection);
    str.set_lob_stream_mode(true);
    str.set_commit(0);

    otl_lob_stream lob;
    lob.set_len(theSizeOfBlob);

    str << lob;
    str << theCurrentAfisId;
    lob << blob;
    lob.close();
}
catch (const otl_exception &oe)
{
    std::cerr << oe.msg;
    throw std::runtime_error("could not write to database");
}
```

I spied at Sourceforge for an example.

I create an otl_long_string that takes the data.
Then I create an otl_stream and bring together the SQL statement and the database connection.
I use an otl_lob_stream to provide the binary data to the otl_stream.
Streaming of the blob data to the otl_stream works fine. But when I hand over the id to the stream, the process dies.

This is the killer instruction:

```
str << theCurrentAfisId;
```

it is a simple int-variable that I hand over.
The effect is very funny: the process doesn't die completely, only the call stack below the current method is gone.
This is the call stack **before** the statement:

```
Thread #1 [fix_stp] 10307 [core: 7] (Suspended : Breakpoint)    
    Drm::TPFixer::DatabaseConnector::writeDB() at DatabaseConnector.cpp:224 0x40b565    
    Drm::TPFixer::DatabaseConnector::fixImpressiontype() at DatabaseConnector.cpp:139 0x40b516  
    Drm::TPFixer::SuperTemplateManager::fixImpressiontype() at SuperTemplateManager.cpp:67 0x4074e3 
    main() at main.cpp:51 0x40477b
```

and this is the complete stack in the very moment **after** the instruction:

```
Thread #1 [fix_stp] 10307 [core: 7] (Running : Step)    
    Drm::TPFixer::DatabaseConnector::writeDB() at DatabaseConnector.cpp:240 0x40b6b2
```

I tried to debug the otl. It seems that the otl finds that it's got all required parameters and starts to run. In that moment it crashes.

The environment that I use:
- OTL 4.0
- CentOS Linux, kernel 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64
- gcc-Version 4.8.5
- Oracle 11g

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Maybe you should update your sql to `UPDATE tbtptemplates SET tptemplate = empty_blob() WHERE afisid=:aid<INT> returning tptemplate into :tptemplate<BLOB, INOUT>` . And the write into the returned lob locator

Comment: Sounds good. Now I get an exception ORA-01008: not all variables bound. This is clear, it is the lob. How can I bind it? I think I'll have to bind it to the stream. Can you give me an example statement, please?

Comment: ... and if I leave away the INOUT, I get an exception ORA-22816: unsupported feature with RETURNING clause :-(

Comment: maybe the BLOB should be OUT only. There should be some examples on OTL site